# Espresso: Clicking on Recycler view with unknown position

Tags: user-interface, automated-tests, ui-automation, android-espresso

I Have Have a list if recycler views in different positions in screen.
 Like below [image]

- I want to click on specific recycler view based on the variable text 'Job#' Inside it.
- But cannot perform the same as I do not know the exact position I should click.
- The position of recycler view keeps changing. Tried below code but it clicks on static position '6'

  recyclerView = onView(
              allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view), isDisplayed()));
      recyclerView.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(6, click()));

I want to know the proper position dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the position in instrumentation tests, in my opinion, is a bad practice as it leads to non-deterministic tests. This is applicable to both `RecyclerView` and `AdapterView`.

So in order to not rely on a position you need an `itemView` matcher for your recyclerview action.

ItemView matcher is a view matcher that matches the itemview of the `ViewHolder`. In your case you need to match a `LinearLayout` that holds the highlighted `RelativeLayout`, which can be represented as `hasDescendant(withText("Job 109"))`

The end solution in your case should look like:

`onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view),isDisplayed())).perform(Recyclerview actions.actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText("Job 109")), click()));`

Comment: Got Error : Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'org.hamcrest.Matcher<android.view.View>', required: 'int'

Comment: Right, I somehow messed up the  copy and paste part- it's supposed to be RecyclerViewAction.actionOnItem

Comment: To be exact:  onView(allOf(withId(R.id.recycler_view),isDisplayed())).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem(hasDescendant(withText("Job#  109")), click()));